# JavaScript cтранное поведение функции

Tags: javascript

```
  function func(el) {
    console.log(el)
  }
  function test() {
    let aa = func($('#el1')) && func($('#el2')) && func($('#el3'))
}
```

Этот код выполняется у меня таким образом, что функция func всегда получает один и тот же элемент el1.
Если же выполнить так как здесь:

```
a = func($('#el1')) 
b = func($('#el2')) 
c = func($('#el3'))
aa = a && b && c
```

то всё ок. Почему такое поведение?

Comment: Наверное, потому что вторая и третья функция не вызываются. Потому что функция возвращает `undefined`.

Comment: Немного не поэтому. Я сильно упростил функцию и удалил return, сорри. Но мне уже подсказали в чем дело. "Если левый аргумент – false, оператор И возвращает его и заканчивает вычисления."

Comment: @ЮрийСтрашко, не `false`, а любое значение которое может быть преведено к `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дам несколько цитат [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops)

**Короткий цикл вычислений**

> JavaScript вычисляет несколько ИЛИ слева направо. При этом, чтобы
> экономить ресурсы, используется так называемый «короткий цикл
> вычисления».
>
> Допустим, вычисляются несколько ИЛИ подряд: a || b || c || .... Если
> первый аргумент – true, то результат заведомо будет true (хотя бы одно
> из значений – true), и остальные значения игнорируются.
>
> Это особенно заметно, когда выражение, переданное в качестве второго
> аргумента, имеет сторонний эффект – например, присваивает переменную.

Оператор И пишется как два амперсанда &&:

> К И применим тот же принцип «короткого цикла вычислений», но немного
> по-другому, чем к ИЛИ.
>
> Если левый аргумент – false, оператор И возвращает его и заканчивает
> вычисления. Иначе – вычисляет и возвращает правый аргумент.
>
> Например:

```js
// Первый аргумент - true,
// Поэтому возвращается второй аргумент
alert( 1 && 0 ); // 0
alert( 1 && 5 ); // 5

// Первый аргумент - false,
// Он и возвращается, а второй аргумент игнорируется
alert( null && 5 ); // null
alert( 0 && "не важно" ); // 0
```

Прменительно к вашему примеру

```
let aa = func($('#el1')) && func($('#el2')) && func($('#el3'))
```

а также

```
aa = a && b && c
```

выполняются по короткому циклу.
А вот само вычисление

```
a = func($('#el1')) 
b = func($('#el2')) 
c = func($('#el3'))
```

выполниться по любому потому что оно так запрограммировано

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли )

Answer (score 3):

А что возвращает `function func(el)`? `undefined`?

Если так, то  здесь: `func($('#el1')) && func($('#el2')) && func($('#el3'))`
вторая и третья часть даже не будут запускаться, так как результат первой `== false` и нет смысла запускать что-то дальше, что связано через `&&`